# Open or Save HTML Document with their associated media files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, winjs

I am working on a Live HTML5 Editor and also published it on windows 8.1 store as BETA version check below link :

[Propan HTML5 Live Editor](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/propan/f8fcdd0c-60e2-4ad9-9186-1d9e845c6a2c)

Here i have a problem of saving media files that are include in html document, i know that for security reasons windows not allow direct path for a file so i fetched its content and display on `x-webview` or an `iframe` for live preview .But how can i open or fetch attached media files with that file and same for saving a HTML document with media files ??

If you have any suggestions ,post here..So,i got your way to do so !!

Comment: Could you clarify what you're doing? You know there's an issue with security, and you're asking how to work around the security issue?

Comment: Actully i wanna fetch links inside the html document Programatically.without any user interface ,so only user have to select html file and all links whether it is a media file or functional file are open with that ?@WiredPrairie